# I have two model in prisma one to many relation but i want to insert data into second model how to do this?

Tags: node.js, express, prisma

I have two model in prisma - one package model and second variation model. They are in one to many relation

```
model Package {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  name String
  title String
  vocavive_user vocavive_user[]
  variations Variation[]
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model Variation {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  expiration Int
  bdt Int 
  discount_bdt Int @default(00)
  usd Int @default(00)
  discount_usd Int @default(00)
  status Boolean @default(false)
  packages Package? @relation(fields: [package_id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  package_id Int?
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

I can insert data variation when I insert package data and variation data at the same time.

```
exports.createPackage = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
  const {
    name,
    title,
    expiration,
    bdt,
    discount_bdt,
    usd,
    discount_usd,
    status,
  } = req.body;
  const newPackage = await prisma.package.create({
    data: {
      name: name,
      title: title,
      variations: {
        create: {
          expiration,
          bdt,
          discount_bdt,
          usd,
          discount_usd,
          status,
        },
      },
    },
    include: {
      variations: true,
    },
  });
  console.log(newPackage);
  res.status(200).json(newPackage);
});
```

But in my case I need to insert value only into variation table.. I tried this

```
exports.createVariation = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
  const newVariation = await prisma.variation.create({
    data: {
      expiration: req.body.expiration,
      bdt: req.body.bdt,
      package_id: req.body.package_id,
    },
  });
  res.status(200).json(`variation Created Successfully: ${newVariation}`);
});
```

but it shows me

> 38 exports.createVariation = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
> 39   const newVariation = await prisma.variation.create(
> Foreign key constraint failed on the field: `Variation_package_id_fkey (index)`
> at RequestHandler.handleRequestError (D:\Firoz\demo_authentication\node_modules@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:34869:13)
> at RequestHandler.handleAndLogRequestError (D:\Firoz\demo_authentication\node_modules@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:34841:12)
> at RequestHandler.request (D:\Firoz\demo_authentication\node_modules@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:34836:12)
> at async PrismaClient._request (D:\Firoz\demo_authentication\node_modules@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:35926:16)
> at async D:\Firoz\demo_authentication\controllers\packageController.js:39:24
> Error:
> Invalid `prisma.variation.create()` invocation in

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please add a tag for the database you are using like `mysql`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message suggests that there doesn't exist a package with id that you are providing in `package_id` field.

You can omit the `package_id` field if it isn't needed or you would need to make sure that package with the value of package_id you are passing exists.